# Authenticate google certificate by c# code?

Tags: c#, .net, security, authentication, .net-4.0

When I browse *google.com* I can ensure that it is *google.com* by clicking in the address bar :

[image]
[image]

But let's assume google is exposing  `Service1`, and I - using c# consume this service (wcf) -

How can my service be assure that he is connecting to google.com ?

I know there is a certificate involved here.

I already  *know* how to read local certificates from my store. but this certificate is not in my store.

Question :

So **How** do ( and in what **stage**) can I read google's certificate data and to assure i'm connecting to them?

Thank you.

Comment: @Eugene Mayevski 'EldoS Corp , I made a test and the result were  http://i.stack.imgur.com/s8n4A.jpg ..... why did i get 2 lines  ? was i dealing with 2 certificates ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = 
    (sender, certificate, chain, policyError) => {
        var subject = certificate.Subject;
        return subject == "CN=www.google.com, O=Google Inc, L=Mountain View, S=California, C=US";
    };
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. but How did you build the `CN=www.google.com, O=Google Inc, L=Mountain View, S=California, C=US` string ? what field of the certificate did you use ?

Comment: In fact I just debugged the code and copied the content of `subject`

Comment: oh sorry the subject in the certificate is with line feeds.  will it still be ok ?

Comment: is there any code in c# not related to WCF ( just for knowledge) ? for webserivce for example

Comment: WebSErivce doesnt have `ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback`. how can a webserivce read the certificate data ?  ( without WCF)

Comment: It is a static method in namespace `System.Net.Security`. Put that code somewhere in your start up codes.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/19269/discussion-between-royi-namir-and-l-b)

Comment: Such comparison is not reliable as the certificate can (and will) be replaced in future and the code will stop working. Instead any valid certificate whose subject CN OR Subject Alternative Name is equal to domain name must be accepted. It's not trivial.

Comment: @L.B beside thanking you I wanted to ask 1 more question  , but you left the chat :-) nevermind :-)